# How to Use Enums instead of column index in C#

Tags: c#, datagridview, enums

i am trying to use Enum as a Datagridview Coloumn index, but failed

My Enums

```
enum _EnmDgvCol
    {
        SrNo,
        Name,
        Qty,
        Rate,
        Amount,
    }
```

and I am trying to as follows:

```
MydataGridView[_EnmDgvCol.Name, 0].Value = "Some Value";
```

but its giving Error

```
The best overloaded method match for 'System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView.this[int, int]' has some invalid arguments
```

if i use following code its works

```
MydataGridView[1, 0].Value = "Some Value";
```

My Question is How to Use Enums instead of column index

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I understand that question is answered and already accepted. But...

You using `Enum` to keep column indexes in memory and get more readability to code

Why you need `Enums` for this, if you have already initialized column objects?
Every column in `DataGridView` have property `Name`(you can set it from Designer for example)

Just give to columns same name as `Enum` values has, and you can use it:

```
this.MyDataGridView.Rows[0].Cells[this.SrNo.Name].Value

// or get index of column

this.MyDataGridView[this.SrNo.Index, 0].Value
```

So you don't need one more `Enum` and you don't need to cast `Enum` to `int` every time you call a `MydataGridView[(int)_EnmDgvCol.Name, 0].Value`

Answer (score 5):

Type cast the `enum` value to `int` for instance you have `_EnmDgvColInstance` that has value as `_EnmDgvCol.Name`

```
_EnmDgvCol _EnmDgvColInstance = _EnmDgvCol.Name;
MydataGridView[(int)_EnmDgvColInstance, 0].Value = "Some Value";
```

Or simply

```
MydataGridView[(int)_EnmDgvCol.Name, 0].Value = "Some Value";
```

Answer (score 2):

i would modify your code slightly (just for readability)

```
enum _EnmDgvCol : int
    {
        SrNo = 0 ,
        Name= 1,
        Qty= 2,
        Rate= 3,
        Amount= 4,
    }
```

and use like this

```
MydataGridView[(int))_EnmDgvCol.Name, 0].Value = "Some Value";
```

Comment: i think, if i will not give int value to enums for example srNo =0, then it will take 0 by default so what is the benefit of assigning values to Enums

Comment: @subhashbhule Readability. and you can live without that as wel.

Answer (score 1):

this line of code also work

```
MydataGridView[(Int16)_EnmDgvCol.Name, 0].Value = "Some Value";
```